# Symfony 3 - best practice for looking up ID

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

So I have a poll class with a  createdBy value (userID of the person who submitted it), then a controller that lists all polls in the poll table

```
    public function indexAction()
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $posts = $entityManager->getRepository(Poll::class)->findBy([], ['createdDate' => 'DESC']);

    return $this->render('poll/admin/index.html.twig', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

My twig template looks a little like this at the momemt

```
        <tbody>
    {% for poll in posts %}
        <tr id="poll_{{ poll.id }}">
            <td> {{ poll.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ poll.createdBy }}</td>
            <td>etc</td>
            <td>etc</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

If I want to display the actual username instead of the createdBy ID, what would the best practice be? I'm using FOSUserBundle

Comment: is there a relation (one to many for example) between your user and poll classes ? if so, you could use it directly into the twig template

Comment: No, users are separate and mostly handled by fosuserbundle (I just have my own User class with a few extra variables, and an event listening to assign a role when they confirm their email)

I know I can add a function to my Poll class, but something seemed wrong about that, especially considering fosuserbundle has findUserBy - I'm just not sure how to make use of it

Comment: To use the findUserBy you just have to pass your arguments like this:

$user_manager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$my_user = $user_manager->findUserBy(array('id' => '123'));

But I would make a relation between the User and the Poll (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) as the User is the "submitter/contributor/participant" of the Poll
And then, when you have a manytomany or another type of relation, you just have to call the association as you created it like:

{{ poll.submitter }}

Comment: Wouldn't I use ManyToOne for a user in my Poll class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple twig extension that converts an integer to a User Object. Obviously it does this by querying the DB in the background, hence, enable Doctrine's Second Level Cache (assuming you use Doctrine) to not hit the DB every time for user Object. It will also help in the controller when you call 
$this->getUser()

Sample Twig Extension

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_SimpleFilter;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Tag;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;

/**
 * @Service("app.twig_extension_hydrate_user" , public=false)
 * @Tag("twig.extension")
 */
class HydrateUserExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *     "em" = @Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hydrate_user_extension';
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('hydrateUser', array($this, 'hydrateUserFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function hydrateUserFilter($user_id)
    {
        $em = $this->em;
        $user = $em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')
            ->queryUserById($user_id);
        return $user;
    }

}
```

Then in a Twig Template as in your example

```
<tbody>
{% for poll in posts %}
<tr id="poll_{{ poll.id }}">
    <td> {{ poll.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ poll.createdBy|hydrateUser.username }}</td>
    <td>etc</td>
    <td>etc</td>
    <td>etc</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

PS: Make sure your clear the your cache even in dev env to ensure code works!

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I wanted! Will give twig extensions a try tonight

Comment: Cool, just comment incase you need further help getting it to work, note that while the code above works, it requires JMSDiExtraBundle for annotating services from within PHP files rather than from config/services.yml.
Cheers.